# Passing a pointer from c# to c++ ends with unexpected results

Tags: c#, c++, .net, com-interop

im trying to pass a pointer from c# to c++, this ends with unexpected result in the c++ side when i always receive the same address even when i send a NULL pointer from the c#.

some details.

note: **this is a different kind of question.**

c++:

```
#pragma pack(push, 4)
        struct CEA708CONFIG 
        {
            BYTE                b608Service;            
            BYTE                bCompactStream;         
            BYTE                pActiveServices[63];    
            LONG                lActiveServiceCount;    //
            POINT               ptAlignmentPosition;    /
        };
        #pragma pack(pop)

        interface
        __declspec(uuid("{F1FAC4B6-5DAA-4875-B76B-8C10A0C0B22E}"))
        ICEA708Decoder : IUnknown {
            virtual HRESULT SetConfig(IN const CEA708CONFIG* pConfig) = 0;
            virtual HRESULT GetConfig(OUT CEA708CONFIG* pConfig) = 0;
        };
```

and the c# part:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
    public unsafe struct CEA708CONFIG
    {
        public byte is608Service;
        public byte isCompactStream;
        public fixed byte activeServices[63];
        public int activeServiceCount;
        public Point alignmentPosition;
    };

    [ComVisible(true), ComImport, Guid("F1FAC4B6-5DAA-4875-B76B-8C10A0C0B22E"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface ICEA708Decoder
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        int SetConfig([In] IntPtr config);
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetConfig([Out] out CEA708CONFIG config);
    }
```

and the code that actually does the work:

```
 int     structSize = Marshal.SizeOf(cc708Config);
    IntPtr  structPtr  = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(structSize);

    Marshal.StructureToPtr(cc708Config, structPtr, false);

    if (0 != (hr = CC708DecoderConfig.SetConfig(/*structPtr*/IntPtr.Zero)))
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Couldn't SetConfig() because: " + DirectShowLib.DsError.GetErrorText(hr));
    }
```

as you can see i even tried to send IntPtr.Zero, which ended with the following address in the c++ part: 0x0bb00058.

my guess is that something is wrong with DS register, not sure though.

**edit: whenever i step into to the c++ part of SetConfig()'s, i can see that 'this'' address is 0x0003, how is it possible?**

Comment: Can you try changing the c# definition of `SetConfig` to take `void*`, and see if passing `(void*)0` gives you the same result?

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk: that didn't work either, still receving same pointer: 0x0acc0058